# plotting time series + forecast with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following time series and base `R` code that plots it along with its forecast. I want to recreate the plot using `ggplot` but I'm not sure how.

```
timeseries = ts(c(426, 386, 417, 448, 466, 418, 530, 587, 709, 751, 888, 834, 857, 847), 
start=2008, end=2021, frequency=1)

fit=auto.arima(timeseries)

forecast = forecast(fit, h=4, level=95)

plot(forecast, main= 'forecast (95%)', col='black', type='b', lwd='1.4')
```

[image]

Plotting the actual time series is easy, but I don't know how to add the forecast along with the confidence interval.

```
df=data.frame(year=2008:2021, timeseries=timeseries)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=year, y=timeseries)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(forecast)
library(timetk)

# Supplied data
timeseries = ts(c(426, 386, 417, 448, 466, 418, 530, 587, 709, 751, 888, 834, 857, 847), 
                start=2008, end=2021, frequency=1)

fit=auto.arima(timeseries)

forecast = forecast(fit, h=4, level=95)

# ggplot approach
fc_df <- forecast |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(index = 2022:2025)

timeseries |> 
  tk_tbl() |> 
  bind_rows(fc_df) |> 
  ggplot(aes(index, value)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = `Lo 95`, ymax = `Hi 95`), fill = "grey80") +
  geom_point(aes(y = `Point Forecast`), colour = "blue") +
  labs(title = "Forecast (95%)")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>